# Angular 9.1 upgrade - broken unit tests on Jenkins

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jenkins, karma-jasmine

I upgraded project from angular 9.0 to Angular 9.1 and after that upgrade I am still getting following error during jenkins pipeline

```
DEBUG [Chrome Headless 83.0.4103.116 (Linux x86_64)]: CONFIGURING -> EXECUTING
Chrome Headless 83.0.4103.116 (Linux x86_64): Executed 0 of 0 SUCCESS (0 secs / 0 secs)
[1A[2KChrome Headless 83.0.4103.116 (Linux x86_64) ERROR
  An error was thrown in afterAll
  Script error.
```

It does not happen in regular tests on locale machine. All tests pass. Only in Jenkins.
I tried different Angular 9.1 versions, different karma, jasmine versions, different config of karma, different karma reporters and nothing helped. I also tried to change test code - change beforeEach with beforeAll, removing AfterAll or adding AfterAll as blank function and still error in afterAll. Also I tried everything I found on internet which should resolve this issue but nothing helped so existing answers to this error won't do anything. Also I cannot run tests in Chrome in Jenkins, just ChromeHeadless, so debugging is harder. Even karma config for logging level DEBUG did not tell more.

Here is my karma config.

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
    plugins: [
      require('karma-jasmine'),
      require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
      require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
      require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
      require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
    ],
    client: {
      clearContext: false // leave Jasmine Spec Runner output visible in browser
    },
    coverageIstanbulReporter: {
      dir: require('path').join(__dirname, 'here is secret dir path'),
      reports: ['html', 'lcovonly', 'text-summary'],
      fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
    },
    reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['Chrome'],
    singleRun: false,
    restartOnFileChange: true
  });
};
```

Here is example test: (threw the same error even with blank tests (blank it, blank beforeEach,...))

```
describe('State: DataView', () => {

  /*
   * Initializing some conditions
   */
  beforeEach(() => {

    ...some test init
  });

  afterAll(() => {
    TestBed.resetTestingModule();
  });

  /*
   * Testcase for AddConditionWith()
   */
  it('AddConditionWith', () => {
    ...some testing
  });

  /*
   * Testcase for getIndex()
   */
  it('getIndex', () => {
    ...some testing
  });
.... more code
```

and here are relevant dependencies

```
"@angular/animations": "9.1.11",
    "@angular/cdk": "9.1.3",
    "@angular/common": "9.1.11",
    "@angular/compiler": "9.1.11",
    "@angular/core": "9.1.11",
    "@angular/forms": "9.1.11",
    "@angular/material": "9.1.3",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "9.1.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "9.1.11",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "9.1.11",
    "@angular/router": "9.1.11",
    "@angular/upgrade": "9.1.11",

"jasmine-core": "3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "4.2.1",
    "karma": "4.4.1",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "3.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "1.5.2",
    "karma-teamcity-reporter": "1.1.0",
    "karma-typescript": "4.1.1",
```

I would really appreciate some help, because I am lost in this and I even do not know what else to try. Thanks.

Comment: I tried it with Angular 9.0 and problem is not there. Maybe bug in Angular 9.1 itself ?

Comment: bug happens also in newer 9.1 dependencies (newest stable releases at this date - 21.7.2020)